# How to delete a row that has content related to a cell from another row in another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to know if it's possible to have a script to delete a row from Sheet2 when the row from Sheet1 with the name mentioned Sheet2 is removed.

[Link to test/sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Shl3z09DvOEgKwTAZG7D8RvlKdgd5LIZ4c0uOr4w1-Q/edit?usp=sharing)

**EXAMPLE:**

1. The row 5 from my [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1xDr.png) is what I need to delete.
2. The content of this row is displayed in row 6 of [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhIGK.png).
3. If I delete the row 5 from Sheet 1, the data of [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIilL.png) gets messed up.

The solution of this problem is probably **an edited triggered script that will delete the row from Sheet2 that contains the name of the student in Sheet1**, but I can't develop this script because I'm a totally beginner.

**Anyone could help me?**

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You have to use an on change installable trigger. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For this youre halfway there, its true you need to program a function that acts upon a event. Do read up on the GAS documentation before asking.

Heres some example of how you should do it. If youre not familiar with javascript , do read up on javascript before using google apps script framework.

```
    function onEdit(e){
  otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  lastrow = otherSheet.getLastRow()
  mainSheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:B7").getValues()
  for (let i = lastrow ; i > 1 ; i--){
    targetcell = otherSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()
    if(targetcell != mainSheetData){
      otherSheet.getRange(i,1).clearContent()
otherSheet.getRange(i,2).clearContent()
    }
  }
}
```